# javascript/Jquery - check if number exists before a character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox which allows user to enter only numeric values and 'y' and 'm' values.

```
function ValidateAge(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if ((charCode == 89) || (charCode == 77) || (charCode == 109) || (charCode == 121)) {
    return true;
  }
  if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

How do I validate the textbox to check that there should always be a number before 'y' and 'm'.

Update:

1. There will always be either y or m.
2. y and m should always be preceded by a number
3. Both Y and M can be there in a textbox
4. The y and m could be entered either as lowercase or uppercase

Comment: you can always take the character preceeding the 'y' or 'm' and then check if it coerces to a integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
function ValidateAge(text){
  var reg = new RegExp(/^((\d+)y*m*)+$/ig); // 'ig': Case insensitive match
  return reg.test(text);
}

ValidateAge('123m'); // true
ValidateAge('1y'); // true
ValidateAge('a123m'); // false
ValidateAge('123ms'); // false
ValidateAge('1ymmmmm1y1m1y22yyyy3'); // true
ValidateAge('1my'); // false
```

Comment: Thanks sugars for the prompt reply. If I send '1y7m' as text the validation fails. Can you please advise how to resolve this.

Comment: @HappySingh I've updated the anwser. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks sugars - just one more thing - can I restrict that y should always come first i.e before m?