# Javascript/Jquery - restrict user to enter number before a letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with numbers and two alphabets 'y' and 'm'. I want to extract the numbers before y and m to get the years value and month value. The user can enter say 8y6m or anything. I want to have a validation that user should always enter first number followed by y and then number followed by m. So this is the validation function I have written so far:

```
function ValidateAge(text){
  var reg = new RegExp(/^((\d+)(y|m)*)+$/);
  return reg.test(text);
}
```

It validates true if user enters 1m6y or 1y6m.

To do: Validation to check the y should comes before m i.e it should be number followed by y and then number followed by m

Comment: I can't understand what you really want 
You want the user only enter n,y,n,m
while n is any number ?

Comment: yes - a number to specift the year and month

Comment: I think you asked the same question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797052/javascript-jquery-check-if-number-exists-before-a-character . Does that question does not gave you the correct answer?

Comment: It does not check whether y was entered before m or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First,** decide how will you construct the RegExp object:

- Using the `RegExp` constuctor:

  ```
  new RegExp("^((\\d+)(y|m)*)+$")
  ```
- Or with the RegExp literal:

  ```
  /^((\d+)(y|m)*)+$/
  ```

But don't mix these two. Doing so don't throw any errors, instead, will produce unexpected results.

I recommend using the latter, as in the former, you have to double-escape anything (note `\\` before `d`)...

**Second,** if you want to create a specific order for the values, then don't use groups with multipliers.

Also, multiplied capturing groups will capture only the last iteration.

So, your RegExp should look like:

```
/^(\d+)y(\d+)m$/
```

Or to make month omittable (optional):

```
/^(\d+)y(?:(\d+)m)?$/
```

Or, to require at least one, use a zero-length assertion:

```
/^(?=.*(?:\d+y|\d+m))(?:(\d+)y)?(?:(\d+)m)?$/
```

Both of the above will capture the year as first and the month as second, for later use.

Answer (score 0):

using the solution provided here you can validate your years and months
[Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797052/javascript-jquery-check-if-number-exists-before-a-character)

and then you can check if y before m using index of

```
yIndex = yourString.indexOf("y");
mIndex = yourString.indexOf("m");
if(yIndex<mIndex) return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: If `y` isn't found, this will return true: *If the specified string not found, `indexOf` will return `-1`*, and `-1` is clearly smaller than all natural number (0, 1, 2, etc.).

Comment: Check the question in the link